Get the Class type of a class having generic parameters
Is it possible in Java to get the Class type of a class having generic parameters?
For example, if I have this class:
public class Foo<T> {}

I'd like to get a Class instance typed like this:
// This does not compile and cannot be cast
Class<Foo<?, ?>> clazz = Foo.class

I need that because of a library I'm using. It provides an abstract class with a generic parameter and a constructor waiting for a Class argument. This argument is typed like the class parameter:
public abstract class AbstractBar<T> {
    protected final Class<T> clazz;

    protected AbstractBar(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}

And I'd like to extend this class like this:
public class Bar extends AbstractBar<Foo<?>> {
    public Bar() {
        // But Foo.class is not Class<Foo<?>>, it is Class<Foo>
        super(Foo.class);
    }
}

For now, I'm content to do like this, but I don't like warnings:
public class Bar extends AbstractBar<Foo> {
    public Bar() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }
}


If I understand correctly, this answer is what you need.
